# InnerBlocks inside custom ACF block duplicate content

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, advanced-custom-fields

I use NextJS and Wordpress as headless CMS. I created a custom ACF block with two <InnerBlocks />.

PHP code of my block:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <InnerBlocks />
    </div>
    <div>
        <InnerBlocks />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add content to the first Inner  block, the same content appears in the second Inner block. Content is completely duplicated in blocks. How can I separate these blocks and add different content to them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3McQa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpP6d.png)

Code block.json:

```
{
  "name": "acf/columnswide",
  "title": "Columns Wide",
  "description": "A columns with full width",
  "category": "design",
  "keywords": ["columns", "full columns", "wide"],
  "icon": "columns",
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "acf": {
    "renderTemplate": "./columnsWide.php",
    "mode": "preview"
  },
  "supports": {
    "align": false
  },
  "example": {},
  "edit": "./columnsWide.php",
  "save": "./columnsWide.php"
}
```

Register my block in functions.php:

```
add_action('acf/init', 'acf_init_block_types');
function acf_init_block_types(){
  if (function_exists('register_block_type')) {
    register_block_type(get_template_directory() . "/template-parts/blocks/columnsWide/block.json");
  }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly does this have to do with Next.js or React if your code is in PHP?

Comment: Think you may need to rethink the setup to achieve this.  See this post on the ACF website: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/used-innerblocks-multiple-in-one-acfblock/